# Condense JSON for bandwidth efficiency

Tags: arrays, json, compression

I posted some code to store JSON (arrays specifically) more efficiently on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128882/condense-json-for-bandwidth-efficiency) but it started to attract StackOverflow type responses, so I thought I would post here to debate the purpose not the code.

JSON is quickly becoming the formatting standard of choice for quick, convenient, and reliable machine to machine communications. It is flexible and widely supported but it has some drawbacks when it comes to data payloads like those from databases. A JSON payload from a database table named fruits might look like this:

```
[{"id":1,"abbreviation":"appl","name":"Apple"},
{"id":2,"abbreviation":"pear","name":"Pear"},
{"id":3,"abbreviation":"bana","name":"Banana"},
{"id":4,"abbreviation":"bkby","name":"Blackberry"},
{"id":5,"abbreviation":"strw","name":"Stawberry"},
{"id":5,"abbreviation":"pech","name":"Peach"},
{"id":6,"abbreviation":"plum","name":"Plum"}]
```

Most of the data in this payload is repeated because of the array keys. This is very inefficient and troublesome from a bandwidth perspective. I've come up with a way to compress the JSON by removing the keys and putting them on the first row of the array like this:

```
C[["id","abbreviation","name"],
[1,"appl","Apple"],
[2,"pear","Pear"],
[3,"bana","Banana"],
[4,"bkby","Blackberry"],
[5,"strw","Stawberry"],
[5,"pech","Peach"],
[6,"plum","Plum"]]
```

I know that gzip is typically used to reduce the bandwidth required for a payload but I figured why not do both? Gzip is loss-less meaning it can only compress so much as it has to restore everything exactly as it was. Better storage efficiency combined with gzip with give the best results.

My question is what are the pros and cons to this suggestion. It's been suggested that the processing overhead on this is not worth it. I debate that as bandwidth is much more expensive than processing power these days. Am I wrong? Am I missing something? If you can cut your payload by more than half, isn't it worth it?

Comment: It sounds like you are some type of Linux system. If so, they have zip for Linux and zip has several modes of compression if you want to go there. [Zip for Linux](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/zip.html). [7 zip also has](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) a very good compression rate. And they have source and binaries for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

> "I debate that as bandwidth is much more expensive than processing power these days."

That depends on how much data you are sending and how often. If you send a 5gb file 10x a day, that's a lot of data so consider compressing it. If you send a 5kb file 10x a day, that's hardly any bandwidth at all *for the average high speed connection*. It also depends on the receiver's connection speed. 50gb of data over 3.5mb/s connection (what I used to have) will take a while for a receiver to download.

[The Archive Compression Test](http://compression.ca/) is still there but I don't know when it was last updated. It compares lots of archivers under various conditions (images, text, etc) with links to all of them.

Your individual application decisions should be based on these items and more. 
Then adjust the application over time as conditions change. I.e. make it easy for a competent user to plug in different archiving programs if they need more compression.

Comment: Good suggestion on the compression test. I ran a quick test with an online gzip tool and got a 10% compression improvement using this compression and gzip vs just using gzip. That's just with the above data examples. With mobile it cannot always be assumed everyone will have a high speed connection always.